# NodeJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a CronJob that calls an API and store its response in the database:

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
const btc_price_ticker = require("../../controllers/BtcExchange/Ticker");
const currency = require("../../controllers/Currencies/CurrenciesController");

module.exports = new CronJob("* * * * * *", async function() {
  const {
    ticker: { sell }
  } = await btc_price_ticker.getBtcPrice();
  currency
    .update({
      params: {
        id: "5cbdf078f5bcec257fcec792"
      },
      body: {
        exchange_rate: sell,
        lastUpdate: Date.now()
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

It works fine, however I receive a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`

I'm using the same function to update the database I use when updating by my API:

```
module.exports = {
  async update(req, res) {
    const currency = await Currency.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      new: true
    });
    return res.json(currency);
  }
};
```

The `TypeError` happens in the `return res.json(currency)`, and it only happens when it's called by the CronJob. When I put new information by API, it doesn't show any error.

I think it happens because when I call the function in `CronJob`, I just pass the `req` by parameter, but I don't know how to solve it. What am I supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have express using bodyparser

Comment: You're calling `update()` without passing the response object as the second argument

Comment: Yes @alfasin, you are right. I'm pretty sure this is the error, but I don't know what should I pass as the response object

Comment: @OtavioBonder Ideally you should simply call `Currency.findByIdAndUpdate` or any other common util function in the Corn rather than mocking `req` and `res`

Comment: If you're using cron-job, why do you need req/res from the first place?

Comment: @alfasin because I was using a controller that receives a route call by express. However, I decided to implement the cron update accessing directly the database

Comment: @OtavioBonder that's exactly what I suggested in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a famous saying which says that you can solve almost any problem in CS by adding another layer of indirection. This is one of those cases:

Instead of of declaring your module as:

```
module.exports = {
  async update(req, res) {
    const currency = await Currency.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      new: true
    });
    return res.json(currency);
  }
};
```

Separate the logic from the route-logic:

```
module.exports = {

  async getCurrency(id, params) {
      const currency = await Currency.findByIdAndUpdate(id, params, {
        new: true
      });
      return currency;
  }

  async update(req, res) {
    const currency = await getCurrency(req.params.id, req.body);
    return res.json(currency);
  }
};
```

Now the route can call `update()` and the cron-job can call `getCurrency()` directly.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, maybe my approach isn't the best, but since I'm passing an undefined object to `update()`, and I don't need the response, I edited the `update` function:

```
async update(req, res) {
    const currency = await Currency.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      new: true
    });
    if (res !== undefined) {
      return res.json(currency);
    }
  }
```

So, since res is undefined, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score -1):

It's because both `req` and `res` is `undefined` (or atleast not the proper `request` and `response` object) when the route is not requested by client (which is the case here).

Simplest solution I can think of is mock (or make an actual call) a client call in your `cron` job by using modules like `axios`, `request`, `request-promise` (with `Promise` wrapper on top of request) like:

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

module.exports = new CronJob("* * * * * *", async function() {
  try {
    const {
      ticker: { sell }
    } = await btc_price_ticker.getBtcPrice();
    // assuming your server is running in localhost, port 3000 and route is 'myapi/:id'
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/myapi/5cbdf078f5bcec257fcec792";
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      uri : url,
      json: true,
      body: {
        exchange_rate: sell,
        lastUpdate: Date.now()
      }
    }
    const response = await rp(url);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Since you can execute the `db` methods, a simpler alternative would be to directly execute `Currency.findByIdAndUpdate` in your `cron` job. I don't see any reason why you would want to call your `route` in your code.

Comment: This will make the `Corn` dependent on the server, and will also introduce some latency.

Comment: I don't know the use case, but he's running a `cron` against a `route`. Am just providing *a* solution to OP. If it were me I'd directly execute `Currency.findByIdAndUpdate` I don't see any reason to call the route on your own server for `cron`

Comment: Exactly, that will be the optimum approach.

Comment: Yes @naga-elixir-jar your approach of calling directly the `Currency.findByIdAndUpdate` is much better. I'll implement this way

Comment: Well then, let me add that to the answer :)